# git-p4 : No such file or directory

Tags: git, perforce

I am trying to use git-p4 on Linux and added the git-p4.py to my .gitconfig. However, on clone, I got this error:

```
math@math:/mnt/d$ git p4 clone //depot/path/main@all
Importing from //depot/path/main@all into main
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /mnt/d/main/.git/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 3703, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 3697, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 3571, in run
    if not P4Sync.run(self, depotPaths):
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 3411, in run
    changes = p4ChangesForPaths(self.depotPaths, self.changeRange, self.changes_block_size)
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 807, in p4ChangesForPaths
    changeEnd = p4_last_change()
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 266, in p4_last_change
    results = p4CmdList(["changes", "-m", "1"])
  File "/home/math/bin/git-p4.py", line 492, in p4CmdList
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's directory or file is supposed to exists ? I' ve set up the following env variables: P4HOST,P4PASSWD,P4PORT,P4USER.

Comment: Perhaps the `p4` executable is not in your PATH? It looks like git-p4.py is attempting to run `p4 changes -m 1` and getting "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem right now. And yes, @BryanPendleton was right: you just need to add `p4` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: Confirmed. My experience here was the same; adding a p4 binary to my path made the magic flow.